# Missing topic name when "content_available" is set

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

we're trying to integrate GCM messaging on our iOS app. We use topic messaging to send messages to a group of devices subscribed to the same topic.

During the developemnt we noticed that enabling the "content_available" flag to let the app receive notifications while in background the message we receive is missing the topic name, so if the app is subscribed to multiple topics we're not able to determine which topic was the sender of the message.

Notification sent using HTTP api:

```
{
    "to":"/topics/user_5",
    "data":{"action":"sync","what":"user"},
    "collapse_key":"866c9b6f36461511697a5089fe4b0d8e",
    "delay_while_idle":true
}
```

Notification received on iOS:

```
{
    action = sync;
    "collapse_key" = 866c9b6f36461511697a5089fe4b0d8e;
    from = "/topics/user_5";
    what = user;
}
```

Notification sent using HTTP api, with "content_available" flag set to true:

```
{
    "to":"/topics/user_5",
    "data":{"action":"sync","what":"user"},
    "collapse_key":"866c9b6f36461511697a5089fe4b0d8e",
    "content_available":true,
    "delay_while_idle":true
}
```

Notification received on iOS:

```
{
    action = sync;
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = "0:1436954611368845%1f9e30f91f9e30f9";
    what = user;
}
```

Is it the expected behaviour or is it a GCM bug? Is there someone else struggling with the same thing?

Comment: A workaround would be to add the topic to the data portion of the message.  Unfortunately I don't know if what you're seeing is a bug or a weird difference in behavior between an APN notification and a GCM notification.  Please update if you find out!

Comment: According to GCM documentation, "content_available" should be in data, did you try put content_available inside data